# Is it possible to write multiple DOM objects to a single Xml file?

Tags: xml-parsing

Is it possible to write multiple DOM objects to a single Xml file? 
To make it more clear, i have multiple sources and only one result(I want to write all the source objects into a single xml file). 
transformer.transform(source, result); 
How do i use transform object and get this done?

Comment: Which language and platform are you trying to find the answer for?

Answer (score 0):

The important part is to first import the child node from the first document (including it's children) into the second document, then you just choose a node in the second document to insert before or after and use the reference you got when you did the import and insert it.

In Java:

```
Node childRef;

childRef = secondDocument.importNode(childNodeFromFirstDocument,true);
newParentNodeInSecondDocument.insertBefore(childRef,newParentNodeInSecondDocument.getFirstChild());
```

then use the transformer to output the XML of the second document

In C# it is very similar:

```
 XmlNode childRef = secondDocument.ImportNode(childNodeFromFirstDocument, true);
 XmlNode root = secondDocument.FirstChild;
 root.InsertBefore(childRef, newParentNodeInSecondDocument);
```